# css class to change a colour conditionally

Tags: html, css

If I have the following css:

```
label {
    color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

Is it possible to amend that to add a condition to change the colour to red if the label has the class "error"?
I know I can conditionally add the class to the label in html but I'm wondering if I can do it in css, as the label won't exists until an input error occurs.

Comment: You need to use javascript, or some library/framework like vuejs / angular / react

Comment: Did you try using `label.error` in your CSS?

Comment: Like `label.error { color: red ;}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking for this targeting ?

```
label.error { color: red ; }
```